# PHP Version 7.1.18-1 on ubuntu16.04.1 xdebug is not working. How to enable it?

Tags: 16.04, php7, xdebug

I have installed php 7.1 in ubuntu 16.04 trough the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1-fpm
```

After this step I just followed the instructions from `Xdebug Tailored Installation Instructions` as follow:

```
Summary
Xdebug installed: no
Server API: FPM/FastCGI
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 7.1.18-1
Zend API nr: 320160303
PHP API nr: 20160303
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
Configuration File Path: /etc/php/7.1/fpm
Configuration File: /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
Extensions directory: /usr/lib/php/20160303
Instructions
Download xdebug-2.6.0.tgz
Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-2.6.0.tgz
Run: cd xdebug-2.6.0
Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize.

As part of its output it should show:

Configuring for:
...
Zend Module Api No:      20160303
Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize. Please follow this FAQ entry and skip the next step.

Run: ./configure
Run: make
Run: cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php/20160303
Edit /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini and add the line
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so
Restart the webserver
```

After restarting the webserver (NGINX) I can't see the xdebug extention in  the phpinfo() display:

[image]

This is my php.ini: /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so
```

Even xdebug 2.5.5 as suggested [here in this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103967/is-xdebug-supported-for-php7-1-1) is not working, not even the [Xdebug 2.7.0alpha1](https://xdebug.org/download.php)

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.18-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun 11 2018 14:22:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.18-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue you as you. Despite having used the tailored instructions multiple times in the past, they don't seem to want to work on this particular configuration, and I can't tell exactly why.

However, I had success installing it very simply using:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xdebug
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Don't know if you're still having the issue, but I hope it helps someone. Same issue from here: https://petersproblems.wordpress.com/